# C++ on iOS - EXC_BAD_ACCESS error for class scope variable access

Tags: c++, ios, xcode, exc-bad-access, openframeworks

I can't access the curWaitTime variable in the draw(...) method, it crashes with a EXC_BAD_ACCESS error. It's not even dynamically allocated!

```
#include <string>
#include "ofMain.h"
#include "Colour.h"
#include "ColourScheme.h"

#define NOTIFICATION_TEXT_SIZE          60
#define NOTIFICATION_FADE_OUT_TIME      2

class Notification {
private:
    char *text;
    float curWaitTime;

    void setGlColour( Colour *colourScheme, int colourType, float alphaPercentage ) {
        glColor4f( colourScheme[colourType].r,
                  colourScheme[colourType].g,
                  colourScheme[colourType].b,
                  colourScheme[colourType].a * alphaPercentage );
    }

public:
    float screenWidth, screenHeight;

    Notification( const char *_text, float width, float height  ) {
        text = new char[255];
        strcpy(text, _text);
        screenWidth = width;
        screenHeight = height;
        curWaitTime = NOTIFICATION_FADE_OUT_TIME;
        NSLog(@"Notification created!");
    }

    ~Notification() {
        delete text;
    }

    bool draw( Colour *colourScheme, ofTrueTypeFont *font, float deltaTime ) {
        // update timer
        curWaitTime -= deltaTime;
        if( curWaitTime <= 0.f ) {
            return false;
        }

        //draw
        setGlColour( colourScheme, COLOUR_BACKGROUND_COL3, curWaitTime / NOTIFICATION_FADE_OUT_TIME );
        font->drawString(text, screenWidth/2 - (font->stringWidth(text)/2), screenHeight/2);

        return true;
    }
};
```

It's really confusing me, this normally works. Any ideas? I'm using XCode and coding for iOS with OpenFrameworks

Comment: How is the particular `Notification` instance allocated? BTW: You need `delete [] text`, and you need to follow the "rule of three" or bad things will happen.

Comment: You are most likely calling `draw` through an invalid/NULL pointer.

Comment: @molbdnilo: yes, thanks, forgot

Comment: `for( int i = 0 ; i < MAX_NOTIFICATIONS ; i++ ) {
        if( notifications[i] == NULL ) {
            notifications[i] = new Notification([text UTF8String], screenWidth, screenHeight);
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;`

Comment: @Casey: The exception occurs within the draw method so the object itself is not null

Comment: @user781729 That's actually the most common reason. Contrary to e.g. Java, C++ doesn't necessarily complain if you call a member function on `null` - symptoms usually occur only when you access any of the data that isn't there. Do you check that it's not null before you call it?